# How do I add a Bash script to my Panel as a widget?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, kde

I'm a relatively new Linux user (~2-3months), and I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere, maybe I just formulated it wrong. How do I add this script

```
while true; do 
    lscpu | grep MHz
    sensors | grep Tdie
    sleep 1s
done
```

to my Panel as a widget?

Kernel version: 5.6.13-arch1-1

Desktop Environment: KDE Plasma, plasmashell 5.18.5

At the moment, I have it added in my `.bashrc` as an alias but it would be pretty nice to have it in my panel so I could see it at all times.

Comment: Are you looking for a widget capable of running that shell code and showing its output in a box somehow integrated in the Panel? Is this correct? Or are you looking for a way to launch your script from the Panel (opening it in its own terminal window)?

Comment: @fra-san it's more of a "how do I make my own widget" kind of thing, I guess.

Comment: Ok. I think you should edit your question to make this more clear. (I, for one, didn't get that you wanted to see the _output_ of your script in the Panel; but it can be just my fault, of course).

Comment: While "are there widgets that provide this feature?" is likely OK on U&L (best: also tell what you've already searched for, and where), "how can I build my widget?" would likely be too broad (aside: have you looked at the [official documentation](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5)?).  _Aspects_ of it could be on-topic here (those that aren't mainly about coding), while others would be OK on Stack Overflow (those that are). Oh, I see you had already posted this Q on SO: IMO, there you're expected to ask about specific issues with the code you _have_ (once you have it).